# ArgumentError: Invalid URL using savon to interact with SOAP API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, savon

I am trying to connect to a SOAP API using savon.  I can connect to the client and see the operations like in SOAP UI but anytime I try to call a method I receive an invalid URL error.  I've been at this for many hours trying to figure it out adjusting the client but am stuck.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: 'https://api3.drivecam.com/GpsBulkApi/GpsBulkApi.svc?wsdl=wsdl1')

client.operations
 #  => [:login, :ping, :get_points, :get_trips, :get_idles, :get_speeds, :get_pass_through_data, :get_geo_fence_activations, :get_geo_fence_activation_end_reason_types]

client.call(:ping, soap_action: "http://DriveCam.com/Contracts/IGPSBulkData/Ping") or just client.call(:ping)
# => ArgumentError: Invalid URL
```

Comment: Hi, am having this same error,how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your client

```
client = Savon.client(
        wsdl: 'https://api3.drivecam.com/GpsBulkApi/GpsBulkApi.svc?wsdl=wsdl1'),
        log_level: :debug,
        log: true,
        pretty_print_xml: true)
```

That will give you more information about what's **really** going on over the wire.